# Fly-buck converter common mode attenuation

Tags: analog, dc-dc-converter, flyback

I'm designing a "fly-buck" converter, as shown in the example picture below.

For coupled inductor I was planning to use one with 1 kV functional isolation voltage.

This converter needs to be isolated, so the power potential (common-mode) on the input VIN does not "travel" to the VOUT2/GND.

For DC it is obvious that this is the case, but how do I calculate or estimate the common-mode rejection for ac, say 50 Hz or more?

I was looking at the LPD5030V series from CoilCraft, but struggle to find the data needed.

[image: Flyback converter example]

[Generating Isolated Outputs Using Fly-Buck Converter Topology](https://www.digikey.it/it/articles/generating-isolated-outputs-using-fly-buck-converter-topology)

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion. I need both VOUT1 and VOUT2. VOUT1 domain has some optocouplers with data input and output. VOUT2 has a sensor, that needs to be isolated from VOUT1 domain. So ideally no current should flow from VIN to VOUT2 domain, but how do I calculate the maximum current here?

Comment: Please show your actual circuit and explain why you require 50 Hz common mode rejection.

Comment: If it's isolated, then what will you be doing with the VOUT1 pin? Note that this architecture *requires* more load on VOUT1 than VOUT2 to function, or a forced synchronous mode converter. It sounds like you would be better served by a plain old flyback, scratch the buck.

Comment: Fly-back or Fly-buck? What maximum current do you refer to and please do explain what you mean about your requirements for 50 Hz common mode rejection and how that can be perceived given that there are only two supply pins.

Comment: Fly-buck. I'm not sure I'm using the correct term then. But the current I want to calculate, is the current that potentially could flow: (VIN, GND1) -> transformer -> (VOUT2, GND2) -> casing -> (VIN,GND1) PSU  (This would be the unintentionally ground loop)

Comment: Do you want current, or CMRR? CMRR requires a current flow *and* something to flow it into -- some load resistance perhaps (a pair of load resistors to GND in this case, since there are two terminals from the power supply shown). Perhaps you should show more of your system, or the overall system from a high level (what is it, what does it connect to, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [note](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/snva611b/snva611b.pdf?ts=1710338592987&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fds%252Fsymlink%252Flm5017.pdf%253Fts%253D1710332349999%2526ref_url%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.ti.com%25252Fproduct%25252FLM5017%25253Futm_source%25253Dgoogle%252526utm_medium%25253Dcpc%252526utm_campaign%25253Dapp-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-wwe%252526utm_content%25253DLM5017%252526ds_k%25253DLM5017%20Datasheet%252526DCM%25253Dyes%252526gad_source%25253D1%252526gclid%25253DEAIaIQobChMIz-alupzxhAMVEWFIAB2zRA1TEAAYASAAEgL-aPD_BwE%252526gclsrc%25253Daw.ds) about [LM5017](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5017.pdf?ts=1710332349999&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM5017%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dapp-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253DLM5017%2526ds_k%253DLM5017%20Datasheet%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gad_source%253D1%2526gclid%253DEAIaIQobChMIz-alupzxhAMVEWFIAB2zRA1TEAAYASAAEgL-aPD_BwE%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds) which does "explain" an example realization.
Note that the current should not be more than 300 mA (Iout1+Iout2) ...

Note also that the "current" you are watching need "more" data of the "transformer" and its "isolation" from that circuit.